# Mongo can't create the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have some problems working with mongo(mongoose on nodeJS), i think these are newbie questions, but i am new to this stuff and i am learning the beginning steps, basically i created a schema on nodeJS and connected the app to mongoDB. Below is my code for that:

```
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/ShareIdea"

module.exports = function(){
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    var db = mongoose.connect(connectionString);

    require('../app/models/user.server.model');

    return db;
};
```

then on the server side, i instantiate the mongoose, but my main problem is with the form, i want to post the data. my form is this:

```
<form class="form" action="/users" method="POST">
            <div class="some-class">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" name="userChoice" value="programmer" id="y" />
                <label for="y">Programmer</label>
                <input type="radio" class="radio" name="userChoice" value="inovator" id="z" />
                <label for="z">Inovator</label>
            </div>
            <input class="inp" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
            <input class="inp" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
            <input class="inp" type="text" name="userame" placeholder="Username">
            <input class="inp" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input class="inp" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="submit" class="submit inp" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

this calls my router that works well, in my schema i set the names to be the same as here:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstname:String,
    lastname:String,
    email:String,
    username:String,
    password:String,
    userChoice: {type: String, possibleValues: ['programmer','Inovator']}
});

mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

So my database is not creating on its own as i read in other websites, so i typed

> 'use shareIdeas'

in the cmd to create the database, writing

> show dbs

does not show my create database, when i save the form data i don't know if i am actually saving the data, since i don't have the database, i have no idea if it is saving in a different place.

here is how i save the form data:

```
var User = require('mongoose').model('User');

module.exports = {

  create: function(req,res){
  var user = new User(req.body);

  user.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
          return next(err);
      }
      res.json(user);
  });


 },

};
```

Comment: Mongodb creates a database and collection automatically when you enter a record.

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

So here change the user to User.And pass the user which contains the data to save.

var User = require('mongoose').model('User');

```
module.exports = {

  create: function(req,res){
  var user = new User(req.body);

  User.save(user, function (err) {
      if (err) {
          return next(err);
      }
      res.json(user);
  });


 },
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code.

Call the open (connectToMongoDatabase) and close (closeMongoConnection) connection functions defined in the module in `post` method.

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/ShareIdea"

module.exports = {

    connectToMongoDatabase: function () {
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
        mongoose.connect(connectionString);
        console.log("MongoDB connected ...");        
    },

    closeMongoConnection : function () {
        mongoose.connection.close();
    }
};

var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var urlencoded_body_parser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
});

app.use(urlencoded_body_parser);

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    userChoice: { type: String, possibleValues: ['programmer', 'Inovator'] }
});

var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var exports = module.exports;

app.post("/users", function (req, res) {

    console.log(exports);
    exports.connectToMongoDatabase();
    console.log(req.body);
    var user = new UserModel(req.body);

    user.save(function (err, success) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("inserted.......");
            console.log(success);
            res.json(success);
        }
        exports.closeMongoConnection();
    });

});

app.listen(3000);
```

The above code has been tested successfully.

[image: User collection]

[image: User collection data]

Answer (score 0):

You created the database with the name `ShareIdea`but you are giving `use shareIdeas`how can this query shows the data in database that you have created.You should use like this  `use ShareIdea`.You want to see that your database is created or not using `show dbs` this query shows the databases that had the data within it.I created the database in `config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
'mongoUrl' : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/live_stream'
}
```

and in my `app.js` file I gave connection to database and server file

```
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
console.log("Connected correctly to server");
});
```

after creating the schema you should import into the server file i.e, `app.js`

```
var User= require('./models/User');
```